# pandas remove duplicates from a cell

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I need to **remove** the **duplicate numbers in a cell** and **duplicate** **percentage sign in cell**

I have two inputs:

**Input1-**

0. 51 %
1. 4% %
2. (0.9 %)
3. 53 %
4. 44 %
5. 29 %

Name: Paid Loss Ratio , dtype: object

**Req'd output1** :

0. 51
1. 4
2. -0.9
3. 53
4. 44
5. 29

Name: Paid Loss Ratio , dtype: object

**The following script works for this case:**

f1['Paid Loss Ratio '].str.split('%').apply(set).str.join('').str.rstrip()

**Trying to remove the duplicated "% sign in one cell"**

**input2** -

0. ```
     88 %
   ```
1. ```
    102 %
   ```
2. 84 84 %
3. ```
     ( 0.8 %
   ```
4. ```
     93 %
   ```

Name: Constant Loss Ratio , dtype: object

**Req'd Output2** :

0. 88 %
1. 102 %
2. 84 %
3. -0.8%
4. 93 %

**Trying the following but it doesn't work properly:**

re.sub(r'([0-9])(.*)\1+', r'\1', str(ab))

**Trying to remove the duplicated "84" number in one cell**

**Also is there a way to merge these two scripts/pattern?**

Comment: whats wrong with `df['col'].replace('%+','',regex=True).astype(float)` ?

Comment: @Manakin this one works too, so i'm taking a combination of both Answers.. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Manakin i've updated the question a bit, can you see if you can help in the case we have "parenthesis" like -0.8% or -0.9%

Comment: this should do it `df[0].replace('%+','',regex=True).str.strip('()').astype(float)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirement on the first input doesn't match the output since you only seem to want to remove a double percentage sign? If I'm correct I think you could use:

```
(\S+)(?=\s\1)\s
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/09VL2z/13)

---

A sample Python script could be:

```
df = df.replace(r'(\S+)(?=\s\1)\s','', regex=True)
```

Prints:

```
0    51 %
1     4 %
2     9 %
3    53 %
4    44 %
5    29 %
6    88 %
7   102 %
8    84 %
9     Nan
10   93 %
```

Comment: I've updated the question a bit and have added a parenthesis data, can you see if anything can be done of that?.. I need to remove the braces and add a negative sign infront of it....  like -0.8% inplace of (0.8 % or -0.9 in place of (0.9 %)

Comment: @karan, changing your question hindsight is really not a great idea. You are welcome to open many questions (as long as they are good questions). I guess for now you could use two replacements? Maybe use: `df = df.replace(r'\(([^)]*)\)', r'-\1', regex=True)` first and then the suggestion in the answer?